# SwiperJS Pagination only updating at first and last dot but not in between

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination, swiper.js

I'm using SwiperJS in my project and i tried to create a swiper with a pagination. Everything is working expect when Swiping the Pagination Dots arent updating correctly. Only when reaching the first or the last slide it will update. But clicking on the dots works.

My Swiper Configuration:

```
releasesSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper.next-releases', {
 // Optional parameters
 slidesPerView: 6,
 spaceBetween: 20,
 direction: 'horizontal',
 loop: false,
 initialSlide: 0,
 centeredSlides:false,
 createElements: false,
 effect: 'slide',
 roundLengths: true,
 autoplay: false,
 cache: false,

 // If we need pagination
 pagination: {
   el: '.section-content.next-releases .swiper-pagination',
   clickable: true,
 },
});
```

plus my HTML:

```
<div class="swiper section-content next-releases hidden">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper section-content-wrapper">
                        
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

I already tried calling the *swiper.pagination.update* function manually after swiping but that didn't work either.

I also have another Swiper on the same site that works so i dont know why this one should not.

I'm using the latest version of SwiperJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was relatively simple: The initialization of the swiper class was in a for loop and caused problems because of it.

Comment: So what did you change? I have a similair case using the package in combination with vue. The slides are initialised via a v-for.

Comment: I just moved the initialization out of the for loop. I wasnt using the package though i used the normal javascript cdn.